# Trying to pass values from listview to another activity

Tags: android, listview

this question probably has been asked quite a lot but even after all the time i spent searching for a solution i couldnt make it work.

First i found this code which was very useful

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
        Product selectedProduct = arrayList.get(position);

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NuevaActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("nombre", selectedProduct.getName());
        intent.putExtra("contenido", selectedProduct.getContent());
        intent.putExtra("extra1", selectedProduct.getExtra());
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

In which **Product** selectedProduct = arraylist.get(position);    didnt work as it asked for an object from my arraylist

So i changed it to **Object** whatevername = myarraylist(position);

Next i figured out how the putExtra worked and now i have a doubt about it. So i need to get the Strings from the  Array(As taken from this example) with 3 methods called **getName()** **getContent()** and get **Extra()** ?

The problem is the following, How do i create this methods ?

In my actual list view i get my data from a PHP and put the JSONdata in 3 different arrays, should i use this for the 3 methods mentioned above?(Only this time do one for each array)

And if so do i need to write 3 **Object** whatevername = eachdifferentarray(position); in my code?

Thanks in advance for the help, this is new for me so im trying my best to understand it.

Comment: in your NuevaActivity use this code to fetch data put by putextra.                          String nombre = getIntent().getStringExtra("nombre"); for getting nombre you provide your different keys to fetch different values.

Comment: In your NuevaActivity onCreate, get these data from getIntent. 
Intent intent = getIntent();
intent.getExtra("someKey")

Comment: Yes i know this already, the problem is that i dont know how to fetch the data from my arraylist to the putextra, or in other words what method i have to use to get the string from each one of my arrays(And then write this method next to get.**TheMethodUsedForFetchingTheStringFromOneOfMyArrays**).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it
1-Changed Product to Object to get position of my array
2-Had to pass that position to a string
3-Finally pass that string to a put extra

If you want an example it would be something like this:

```
Object ArrayPosition = nameofarray.get(i);

String ValuePosition = ArrayPosition.toString();

intent.putExtra("NameExample",ValuePosition);
```

If you wanted to pass more than one you just have to do one for each

```
Object ArrayPosition1 = nameofarray1.get(i);
Object ArrayPosition2 = nameofarray2.get(i);

String ValuePosition1 = ArrayPosition1.toString();
String ValuePosition2 = ArrayPosition2.toString();

intent.putExtra("NameExample1",ValuePosition1);
intent.putExtra("NameExample2",ValuePosition2);
```

and to pass the putExtra to another activity

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String NameExample = intent.getStringExtra("NameExample");
//*Do whatever logic you need here*
```

Hope this helped someone!

Answer (score 1):

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
        Product selectedProduct = arrayList.get(position);
        Common currentClick = selectedProduct;
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NuevaActivity.class);

        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Here Common is an class which stores the current click item and you can use it on next class 
Eg. Common `currentClick.getYoueyc();`

Comment: The thing is i would like to work with the putextra as i can retrieve it easily in the next activity with intent.getStringExtra

Comment: Common currentClick = selectedProduct;.  It is also.so.easy just String ne 
= selectedProduct.getName();

Comment: Thanks for the help, i found from another source that i  only had to get the string from my object(which has the position from the array) asigning it to a new variable . Somewhat similar of what you posted for this code.